# How to send a properly formatted email using Python and SMTP?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email using Python script but somehow in the format I am expecting the email to come in my mailbox, it is not coming in that format. Below is my method which is sending an email -

```
def send_mail(data):
    sender = 'fromuser@host.com'
    receivers = ['touser@host.com']

    message = """From: fromuser@host.com
    To: touser@host.com
    Subject: Send mail from python!!

    """
    body = 'Some Text\n'
    for item in data:
        body = body + '{name} - {res}\n'.format(name=item['name'], res=item['res'])

    message = message + body

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('corp.host.com' )
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
       print "Mail sent"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print "You can't spam. Mail sending failed!"
```

Here data just have key - value pair.

And I am getting an email like this in my Outlook mailbox -

In the `From:` section in my outlook, below string is coming as it is which is wrong -

```
fromuser@host.com To: touser@host.com Subject: Send mail from python!!
```

And `To:` , `Subject:` section is coming as Empty which is also wrong.

And in the body I am seeing everything coming in a single line but I want the result to be shown as -

```
Some Text

machinA - 0
machineB - 0
machineC - 0
```

How can I represent my data to be shown like this in my Outlook mailbox?

Comment: Headers must be separated by \r\n. Use the email classes to build a proper message.

Comment: @Max is correct here. It looks like you have this now, but if you need an example, let us know.

Comment: sure.. can you provide an example basis on my example?

Comment: Also add the header `Content-Type: text/plain` so that it does not assume html.

Comment: Also, you've accidentally invoked header folding, because your To and Subject lines are indented. Triple quoting will preserve the indentation.

Comment: @Max:Thanks Max for the suggestion. If possible, can you provide an example basis on my example by which I will be able to understand better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since triple quoting preserves all spaces, you were accidentally sending:

```
From: fromuser@host.com
      To: touser@host.com
      Subject: Send mail from python!!
```

This invokes header unfolding: indented lines mean that the header is continued.  So this really is a badly formatted From header.  You need to make sure there are no extraneous spaces.  This fixes up your current example:

```
def send_mail(data):
    sender = 'fromuser@host.com'
    receivers = ['touser@host.com']

    message = """\
From: fromuser@host.com
To: touser@host.com
Subject: Send mail from python!!
"""
    body = '\n\nSome Text\n'
    for item in data:
        body = body + '{name} - {res}\n'.format(name=item['name'], res=item['res'])

    message = message + body

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('corp.host.com' )
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
       print "Mail sent"
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
       print "You can't spam. Mail sending failed!"
```

However, you shouldn't be manually constructing messages at all.  Python includes an assortment of lovely classes in email.message for constructing a message.

```
import email.message

m = email.message.Message()
m['From'] = "fromuser@host.com"
m['To'] = "touser@host.com"
m['Subject'] = "Send mail from python!!"

m.set_payload("Your text only body");
```

Now, you can turn your message into a string:

```
>>> m.as_string()
'To: touser@host.com\nFrom: fromuser@host.com\nSubject: Send mail from python!!\n\nyour text-only body'
```

I will warn you, properly dealing with email is a very large and complex topic, and if you want to use non-ascii, attachments, etc, there's a bit of a learning curve, and you will need to use all the faculties of the email.message library, which has a lot of documentation you should read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.. Now I am able to see From, To and Subject section properly.. But the data is not coming in my mail body at all. Only From, To and Subject section are working fine now.. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: I was trying with your first option as my data is pretty simple and straightforward so going with first option for now..

Comment: You need two \n after the subject. Either add them to the headers section, or before your body.